# OpenAL tone generation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, openal

So I have been looking around for some time now on a way to produce a variable tone on the iPhone using OpenAL, the issue being the Apple has deprecated the ALUT part of OpenAL that has the alutCreateBufferWaveform that would be perfect for this.  I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to make a tone generator using OpenAL on the iPhone SDK.  All I need is the ability to produce a certain frequency tone consistantly over and over again.

This is a last resort so sorry if it sounds kind of stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but it can create a similar effect.

I used this tutorial

http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/

to create an engine that could play a prerecorded sound at different levels.  So even though I have to play the sound from an existing *.caf file, I can modulate the pitch and control looping so it produces any frequency, length, or volume I'm looking for.